# Looking for feedback on an audio rework I made on Elder Scrolls Online -trailer

Tags: demo-reel, demo, sync

Greetings!

Would love some feedback on my first "demo reel", an audio rework I made on the first minute of Elder Scrolls Online -trailer. What do you think? Does it "work"?

I was asked to keep the music side on a small scale.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqGSyjH_8CQ

Answer (score 1):

The detail work is really nice - especially the armour Foley. Though I think you could exaggerate the footfalls on the big guy in the helment - give him some weight. He sounds pretty like on his feet.

Though the monster growls are really nice - it's not obvious that it's coming from the creatures at the end of the cave. I actually thought it was the language of the band of warriors because 1) you have the noises occur when we couldn't see their mouths and 2) the noises were occurring dead centre of the stereo field. You need to pan those to the right - and adjust the reverb so it starts distant - then as we get closer we can hear the monster calls more and more clearly. It's about giving a sense of travel. The characters visual perspective should match the audio perspective.

Oh and crash through the wall at the start is mad distorted. Remember a loud noise isn't about how much it peaks, but the change in the dynamic range and the frequency range it occupies. Maybe play with having a build up - either a ramp or maybe a couple of softer slams before the wall completely falls apart. It's good you've got a bit of after debris in there though.

I think there's a good opportunity to exaggerate some the drama a bit more - when the hand goes up to tell the party to wait, give it a nice heavy leather whoosh or something. Maybe some soft bass booms on the titles too.

Also the end makes no sense to me. There's all these eyes around being perfectly still, but the roar makes it sound like a monster is jumping out...but it's not. It feels like the sound is trying to oversell something that the visuals aren't even doing. Maybe go for a creeping tension rather than jump horror for the end bit? Not sure - just play around with some different ideas and see how they play.

Phew! Good news is that you've got the most difficult parts already sorted. It's super atmospheric and there's all these awesome details in there that make the world feel real.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!

There's actually -3dB headroom or something from the highest peak of the audio track. For some ridiculous reason the people behind Youtube decided that it would be a great idea adding a volume bar, that allows you to set volume up to 250% or something (like in VLC Player). When you have volume at 33% or something, you are at "normal 100%". There's no overlay to point this even out, which is absolutely terrible.

The most confusing part is, not all the videos on Youtube have this "lovely feature" enabled. Why on earth would they add that?!

Thanks again!

Comment: I have never seen this feature? Do you have a link for it in action?